# nodeAffinity & nodeAntiAffinity are ignored

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I am having a problem where I am trying to restrict a deployment to <strike>work on</strike> **avoid** a specific node pool and nodeAffinity and nodeAntiAffinity don't seem to be working.

- We are running DOKS (Digital Ocean Managed Kubernetes) v1.19.3
- We have two node pools: infra and clients, with nodes on both labelled as such
- In this case, we would like to avoid deploying to the nodes labelled "infra"

For whatever reason, it seems like no matter what configuration I use, Kubernetes seems to schedule randomly across both node pools.

See configuration below, and the results of scheduling

**deployment.yaml snippet**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  namespace: "test"
  labels:
    app: wordpress
    client: "test"
    product: hosted-wordpress
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      client: "test"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        client: "test"
        product: hosted-wordpress
        version: v1
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                - key: doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool
                  operator: NotIn
                  values:
                  - infra
```

**node description snippet**
*note the label, 'doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool=infra'*

```
kubectl describe node infra-3dmga

Name:               infra-3dmga
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=s-2vcpu-4gb
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    doks.digitalocean.com/node-id=67d84a52-8d08-4b19-87fe-1d837ba46eb6
                    doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool=infra
                    doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool-id=2e0f2a1d-fbfa-47e9-9136-c897e51c014a
                    doks.digitalocean.com/version=1.19.3-do.2
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=tor1
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=infra-3dmga
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type=s-2vcpu-4gb
                    region=tor1
                    topology.kubernetes.io/region=tor1
Annotations:        alpha.kubernetes.io/provided-node-ip: 10.137.0.230
                    csi.volume.kubernetes.io/nodeid: {"dobs.csi.digitalocean.com":"222551559"}
                    io.cilium.network.ipv4-cilium-host: 10.244.0.139
                    io.cilium.network.ipv4-health-ip: 10.244.0.209
                    io.cilium.network.ipv4-pod-cidr: 10.244.0.128/25
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 20 Dec 2020 20:17:20 -0800
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  infra-3dmga
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Fri, 12 Feb 2021 08:04:09 -0800
```

**sometimes results in**

```
kubectl get po -n test -o wide

NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
wordpress-5bfcb6f44b-2j7kv   5/5     Running   0          1h   10.244.0.107   infra-3dmga   <none>           <none>
```

**other times results in**

```
kubectl get po -n test -o wide

NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
wordpress-5bfcb6f44b-b42wj   5/5     Running   0          5m   10.244.0.107   clients-3dmem   <none>           <none>
```

I have tried using nodeAntiAffinity to similar effect.

And lastly, I have even tried creating test labels instead of using the built-in labels from Digital Ocean and I get the same affect (Affinity just doesn't seem to be working for me at all).

I am hoping that someone can help me resolve or even point out a silly mistake in my config, because this issue has been driving me nuts trying to solve it (and it also is a useful feature, when it works).

Thank you,

Comment: Have you considered using a more simple solution like [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector)? You already have a proper labels for both node pools.

Comment: How did you add label to nodes? I am creating nodes using terraform. Hostnames are automatically assigned in DOKS?

Comment: @Sisir I don’t remember the exact steps but you can do it using doctl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news!

I have finally resolved this issue.

The problem was "user error" of course.

There was an extra `Spec` line further down in the config that was very hidden.

Originally, before switching to StatefulSets, we were using Deployments, and I had a pod Spec hostname entry which was overriding the `Spec` at the top of the file.

Thanks [@WytrzymałyWiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11560878/wytrzyma%c5%82y-wiktor) and [@Manjul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8144188/manjul) for the suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

In the deployment file, you have mentioned `operator: NotIn` which working as anti-affinity.

Please use `operator: In` to achieve node affinity. So for instance, if we want pods to use node which has `clients` labels.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  namespace: "test"
  labels:
    app: wordpress
    client: "test"
    product: hosted-wordpress
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      client: "test"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        client: "test"
        product: hosted-wordpress
        version: v1
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                - key: "doks.digitalocean.com/node-pool"
                  operator: In
                  values: ["clients"] ##Pls use correct label
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion however **anti-affinity** is exactly what we are trying to achieve - in other words "do not schedule any of these deployments on the infra node pool".

In addition, I have tried using **affinity** as you've described here, just as a test, and I have the same issue - it still schedules across both node pools no matter which way we configure it.

And, I have tried using antiAffinity and "In" as well, and it produces the same result.